How do compilers handle more than 2 nodes when making an AST
I am having difficulty understanding how a compiler handles cases with more than 2 nodes.
for example lets say I have a program with 3 defined functions in it. The program is our root nodes and the 3 other functions are the children. does this mean the root node has 3 children nodes now? From my understanding an AST only consists of left and right children nodes. How does the parser handle cases like this?
// AST representation

                Program
            /       |      \ 
      function   function    function

My other assumption is that the parser creates a new node and all its children will be explicitly for functions. for example:
// AST representation

                 Node
                /    \
function declaration  Node
                     /    \
    function declaration   Node

when I look on some online code to AST parsers such as astexplorer.net, it shows that the program has 3 individual children nodes but this makes no sense to me.
I tried to essentially create a parser that creates new nodes for every function but they're linked (see the second AST representation). however I have not finished it and would like to know a conventional way of doing this before proceeding.

"From my understanding an AST only consists of left and right children node": have you read the Wikipedia page on AST?

AST construction freedom
The AST structure is fully up to you to design as long as it is a tree (Abstract Syntax Tree).
There is no standard for defining a proper AST though common conventions is to at least remove whitespace and symbolic elements not relevant to semantics.
Producing an AST according to a grammar
If you want to have the second structure the most trivial way is to design the grammar:
node: function_declaration node | epsilon
function_declaration: function_start function_arguments function_block

Then design the parser implementing this grammar, as an example a recursive descent implementation would look like this:
def node():
    ast = Ast(Type.Node)
    if peek(function_start):
        ast.add(function_declaration())
        ast.add(node())
    
    return ast

def function_declaration():
    # Produce a single node with 3 children
    ast = Ast(Type.function_declaration)
    ast.add(function_start())
    ast.add(function_arguments)
    ast.add(function_block)
    
    return ast

The output ast will be structured as expected.
However, if you want to have the staircase pattern for the function_declaration nonterminal,
you should update the grammar:
node: function_declaration node | epsilon
function_declaration: function_start function_arguments_node
function_arguments_node: function_arguments function_block_node
function_block_node: function_block

And modify the code accordingly:
def function_declaration():
    ast = Ast(Type.function_declaration)
    ast.add(function_start())
    ast.add(function_arguments_node())
    return ast
    
def function_arguments_node()
    ast = Ast(Type.function_arguments_node)
    ast.add(function_arguments())
    ast.add(function_block_node())
    return ast
    
def function_block_node()
    ast = Ast(Type.function_block_node)
    ast.add(function_block)
    return ast

Or update the AST construction using the original grammar to:
def function_declaration():
    ast = Ast(Type.function_declaration)
    ast.add(function_start())
    
    astArgumentsNode = Ast(Type.node)
    astArgumentsNode.add(function_arguments)
    
    astBlockNode = Ast(Type.node)
    astBlockNode.add(function_block)
    
    astArgumentsNode.add(astBlockNode)
    ast.add(astArgumentsNode)
    
    return ast

Essentially, produce the AST according to your grammar and the AST will look like your grammar.
How to update the structure such that it does not reflect the grammar structure?
Suppose that the input is a set of functions:
program: function_declaration*

Or equivalently in BNF:
program: node
node: function_declaration node | epsilon

So a naive implementation:
def program():
    ast = Ast(Type.program)
    ast.add(node())
    
    return ast

def node():
    ast = Ast(Type.Node)
    if peek(function_start):
        ast.add(function_declaration())
        ast.add(node())
    
    return ast

Would produce a staircase pattern, often it is more desirable to have no intermediary node nonterminals as they make the AST unneccessarily larger.
To remove them we could replace the recursive call to make it iterative instead in recursive descent:
def program():
    ast = Ast(Type.program)
    while peek(function_start):
        ast.add(function_declaration())
        
    return ast

This will result in a set of childrens added to the program node directly.
Multi-Pass approach
Alternatively, you can also produce the AST by first following the grammar. This would likely contain staircase patterns when using BNF. Once the first version of the AST is produced you can produce a second version that would inline each 'Node' AST node. This would inline the children to the parent of the 'Node' AST resulting in the structure you described in the first diagram.
A multi-pass system for AST construction is common if the semantics are too complex to derive in an initial parsing stage.
I think these answers should help you further in designing your AST the way you want, and help you understand how other compilers approach this. There are still countless other methods because there are no standards, but these are the more common ones.
